# Spark UDF on Python function

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have created a python function for translating short strings using the GCP Translate API. The codes does something like this.

```
def translateString(inputString, targetLanguage, apiKey):
    baseUrl = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key="
    q = "&q="
    gcpKey = apiKey
    target = "&target="
    sentence = str(inputString)

    #Finialize request url
    url = baseUrl + gcpKey + q + sentence + target

    #SEND REQUEST WITH EXPONENTIAL BACK OFF IN CASE OF ERRORS OF EXCEEDING QUOTA LIMITATIONS API
    session = requests.Session()        
    retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=100)
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    respons = session.get(url, timeout=120)

    if respons.status_code == 200:
      data = respons.json()       
      translatedStr = data["data"]["translations"][0]["translatedText"]
      returnString = str(translatedStr)
      return(returnString)

    else:
      return("Error with code: " + str(respons.status_code))

udfTrans = F.udf(translateString, StringType())

apiKey = *********

dfTempNo = dfToProcess.withColumn("TRANSLATED_FIELD", udfTrans(lit(dfToProcess.FIELD_TO_PROCESS), lit("no"), lit(apiKey)))
```

This work great when looping through a `pd.DataFrame` and storing return variables as we go! But now I need to apply this function on a `spark.DataFrame` so the work can be distributed and have created the following `udfTrans = F.udf(translateString, StringType())` so that it can be applied to `string` column in `spark.DataFrame`.

When I run the UDF on 
`dfTempNo = dfToProcess.withColumn("TRANSLATED_FIELD", udfTrans(lit(dfToProcess.FIELD_TO_PROCESS), lit("no"), lit(apiKey)))` 
it returns no errors but takes forever to run on `dfToProcess` with more than 1 row.

I am unsure if I have misunderstood how UDF's are applied to columns in `spark.DataFrame` . Is it even possible to apply a function like this to a `spark.DataFrame` using a UDF or will I be better off doing this in Python/Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Python `udf`s cannot be parallelised like this, because your `executor` needs to call back to the `driver` for the execution of your `udf`. This unfortunately means that your `udf` is going to be blocking for each row and is essentially serial in its execution.

This can be solved more efficiently using different approaches. As your function is heavily IO bound (more specifically network bound), you could look at something like `ThreadPool` implementation, storing your output in a `Dict`, then calling `SparkContext.parallelize()` on your `Dict` and going from there.

Alternatively, you could write your `udf` in `scala`, as it will be automatically parallel in execution.

Alternatively alternatively, have a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf 
as `pandas` `udf` can be vectorized. Hope this helps!